# How to create single Jenkins project for run in multiple platforms

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins server has multiple slaves with different platforms (Windows, Linux and Mac). I need to run a job in each slave to copy a network folder to each local machine. Here are few questions I have.

1. Can I create a single project with Batch, bash, Mac bash script and add condition to execute.
2. Can I create multiple project for each platform and add condition to run depends on the platform.
3. Is there any use of `Multi-configuration project` for this situation
4. What is the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using a configuration management tool such as [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/) or [Puppet](https://puppet.com), which provides a platform independent DSL to do operations such as copying files.  You could then set up a multi-configuration job in Jenkins to run the same job on each of the different slaves.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create a job in Jenkins that will archive the network folder each time something changes in it, and use the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to take it to the workspace of each slave wether it is Linux or Windows.

Simple, elegant :)